# How to calculate nearest bigger integer divisible by 8 in C++ bitwise operation?

Tags: c++, math, bitwise-operators

I need to calculate the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8. For examples:

1. for `a=0`, the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8 is `0`.
2. for from `a=1` to `a=7`, the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8 is `8`.
3. for `a=8`, the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8 is `8`.
4. for from `a=x*8+1` to `a=x*8+7`, the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8 is `a=(x+1)*8`.
5. for `a=x*8`, the nearest bigger integer devisible by 8 is `a=x*8` itself.

How should I implement this function `int nearestBiggerIntegerDevisibleBy8(int a)` in C++ bitwise operation (fastest)?

Comment: `a = ((a+7)/8)*8` will do the trick. Compiler knows how to optimize the code better than us. Don't bother with bitwise operations for this.

Comment: @Qubit oh yes, you're right

Comment: Doing this with purely bitwise ops is an academic exercise. But your wording makes it seem like it's an optimization question. @ALX23z is right regarding optimization. If you're interested in the academic exercise, please specify.

Comment: @tenfour Well I would not say that regarding the optimization. Clang, gcc, icc will fail to generate as fast code as with my proposed solution. (https://godbolt.org/z/3JrFhm , check MIPS its even worse). It never a bad thing to thrive for some optimization.

Comment: @Eraklon because the two functions don't always have the same output. Change them to operate on `unsigned int` and it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one way to go about it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nearestBiggerInt(int n){ 
    n += 7;
    return (n & ~7);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("%d -> %d\n", i, nearestBiggerInt(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 8
2 -> 8
3 -> 8
4 -> 8
5 -> 8
6 -> 8
7 -> 8
8 -> 8
9 -> 16
10 -> 16
11 -> 16
12 -> 16
13 -> 16
14 -> 16
15 -> 16
16 -> 16
17 -> 24
18 -> 24
19 -> 24
```

Comment: @ALX23z Yes it will.

Comment: if "biggest" in case of negatives should mean "away from zero" then it  doesn't work